# How can I run React in Development mode with .NetCore in IIS?

Tags: reactjs, asp.net-core, iis-10

I've used the Visual Studio template for .NetCore/React web app.  By default, it runs in Development mode using IIS Express.  However, if I set up a site in IIS, and a launch profile, I get an error in the browser:

> AggregateException: One or more errors occurred. (One or more errors
>   occurred. (The NPM script 'start' exited without indicating that the
>   create-react-app server was listening for requests. The error output
>   was: Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, mkdir
>   'C:\Windows\system32\config\systemprofile\AppData\Roaming\npm'

My launchSettings.json has the following for the IIS profile:

```
"IIS": {
      "commandName": "IIS",
      "launchBrowser": true,
      "launchUrl": "http://localhost",
      "environmentVariables": {
        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
      }
    }
```

From the error, it looks like it may be a permission issue that I need to have the IIS app pool running under, but I can't find any documentation that tells me anything about that.

What am I missing?  Again, this is an otherwise unmodified project from the template.  The Startup.cs is running React as would be expected with:

```
app.UseSpa(spa =>
{
   spa.Options.SourcePath = "ClientApp";

   if (env.IsDevelopment())
      { spa.UseReactDevelopmentServer(npmScript: "start"); }
});
```

Answer (score 2):

According to your description, I suggest you could firstly modify the IIS default application pool's identity to make sure it has the permission to run npm.

I suggest you could follow below steps:

1.Open the IIS management console, locate the application pool,find the default application pool and click the advanced setting.

[image]

2. Find the identity setting and modify the build-in account to localsystem

[image]

Then I suggest you could add the npm path in the system environment.

1. Go to Control Panel\System and Security\System and find advanced system settings

[image]

2.Click environment variable

[image]

3.Find the path inside the system variable and add the npm path as below:

```
C:\Users\{username}\AppData\Roaming\npm
```

[image]